# Maven not running JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

My `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
</plugin>
```

But when I do `mvn clean test`

```
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Note that IntelliJ does recognize the test
[image]
(Although when I click the `test` folder and select `Run All Tests`, it says `No tests found`)

Why is Maven not running my unit tests and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the correct annotation `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` ?

Comment: (it will show up as one of the `import` statements at the top of the file with the test)

Comment: in addition see here https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests

Comment: Can you show the whole test class including imports?

Comment: What's the name of the class? Surefire has a naming convention for test classes, see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes

Comment: @amseager No, I wasn't. that fixed the problem. Please feel free to post that as the answer or I can do it for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using JUnit 5 (Jupiter), you need to import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test` (the latter is for JUnit 4).